# Django Rest Framework - React - Unable to login immediately after logout

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

This is very strange. I have a react front end and a django backend with djangorestframework and django-allauth for authentication. Everything works fine from Postman. But in the browser when I successfully sign in, successfully sign out, and then try to sign in again, I get a 401 unauthorized error. The correct user credentials are sent to the server just as the first successful time, yet a 401 error. However, after I refresh the browser then I am able to sign in normally again. I use jwt for authentication and I append the token to the authorization header before sign out. I even tried clearing out the authorization header after a successful sign out but to no avail. It is the same problem with my react native front end. I don't know if this is a react or a django problem. Please does anyone have any idea what the problem might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved! I appended the Token to the authorization header like so:

request.headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`

Except when signing out, every other request did not require the authorization header to be set as above. So after sign out, the authorization header becomes:

request.headers.Authorization = Token null

That null value of the token would make every request after sign out "Unauthorized". So to solve this, I had to set the Authorization header for every request when there is token and then delete the Authorization from the header object when there is no token like so:

delete request.headers.Authorization